# Fourier transform of $f(t)=e^{-X\cosh^2(t)}\cosh(t)$

Tags: fourier-transform

I need to get the Fourier transform of

$$f(t)=e^{-X\cosh^2(t)}\cosh(t)$$

with  $X>0$.
Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: What? I don't understand you ...

Comment: This is not a "do-my-homework" site that you will give any question and somebody will solve it for you.. You must show what you have done

Comment: I'm sorry but really I don't know how to start.

Comment: Perhaps start by writing out the integral you'd need to compute to obtain $\hat{f}(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

## Hint

Im not even sure how to evaluate the result but I imagine this isn't the worst starting point. To "reduce the complexity" of the integral use:
$$ \cosh(t) = \frac{e^{t}+e^{-t}}{2} \\
\cosh^2(t) = \frac{\cosh(2t)+1}{2}$$
Together the hyperbolic cosines can be replaced with exponentials which may be easier to handle if you use appropriate contour integral black magic.